# Shortcut for documenting large search API endpoint in Swagger?

Tags: api, swagger

We have a search page for an internal tool that users will use to search our recipes.  This ends up being ~80 separate fields that may (or may not) be submitted to `POST /search`.

My question is, is there a better alternative to the Swagger documentation that listing every possible field?  For instance, can I somehow reuse the recipe model definition that I reference as the return object in `GET /recipes/{id}`?

```
  '/recipes':
    get:
      summary: Retrieve a set of recipes.
      description: A paginated subset of recipes
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: limit
          description: number of records returned
          required: false
          type: integer
          default: 50
        - in: query
          name: offset
          description: starting record
          required: false
          type: integer
          default: 0
      tags:
        - Recipes
      responses:
        '200':
          description: a subset of recipes
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Recipe'
```

Maybe there's no way around re-defining all these parameters in the following format, but I thought I'd ask:

```
 '/search':
    post:
      description: Robust recipe search
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: id
          description: recipe id.
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: title
          description: Recipe title
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: ingredient
          description: Searches ingredients for an exact match
          required: false
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: ingredientText
          description: Searches ingredients for a subString match
          required: false
          type: string
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't have more than one body parameter in the POST operation.  You *can* have multiple `formData` parameters, though.

My question though is, if you have so many non-required fields for submitting a search, perhaps you are better modeling a complex POST object, which has optional fields for each criteria?  Then you have a single schema being defined, and the user can input what they want by entering the fields they want to use.